# pagination by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I would like to make pagination in jQuery, but it is not working. JavaScript is working, but jQuery code is not working. I think that the variable `num` is the problem.

What is the problem in this code?

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(
    function fn_page(num) {
      document.form1.target = "_self";
      document.form1.action = "";
      document.form1.page.value = num;
      //document.form1.submit();

      /* jQuery("form1").attr('target', '_self').submit(); */
    }
  );
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 <li><a href="javascript:fn_page({$p_num})">{$p_num}</a></li>
```

Comment: `fn_page` is not accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap this function in `(document).ready`.

Change it to this (assuming the `id` of your `form` is `id="form1"`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fn_page(num) {
    document.forms['form1'].target = "_self";
    document.forms['form1'].action = "";
    document.forms['form1'].page.value = num;
    document.forms['form1'].submit();
  } 
</script>
```

And really, since you're using jQuery, you should just stay true to your abstraction:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function fn_page(num) {
    jQuery("#form1").attr("target", "_self");
    jQuery("#form1").attr("action", "");
    jQuery("#form1 input[name=page]").val(num);
    jQuery("#form1").submit();
  } 
</script>
```